# Templating jinja 2 variables for ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following scenario:
Variables named like:

```
size_1: 1
size_2: 2
size_3: 3
nb_of_sizes: 3
```

And I want to template them in a jinja2 file with an iteration, to get something like:

NB-1-01

NB-1-02

NB-2-01

NB-2-02

NB-3-01

NB-3-02

The index in the end of the name is not important, as I succeeded to get it.

What is important is how to template the value of the **size** parameter.

I tried with 2 for loops, the first one is working fine (with index) but I don't know how to replace the second variable {{ index2 }} in the name of the size : size_{{ index2 }}

This is my attempt:

```
{% for index in range(1, nb_of_servers + 1) %}
{% for index2 in range(1, number_of_sizes + 1) %}
  - name: "NB-{{ index2 }}-0{{ index }}"
    size: "{{ size_{{ index2 }} }}"
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You cannot nest jinja2 markers. Moreover, since you are looking for a "top level" var dynamically, you'll have to usie a [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) => `size: "{{ lookup('vars', 'size_' + index2) }}"

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be that you have enclosed `size_` inside the Jinja templating markers `{{`.

As you seem to require just `size_1`, `size_2`, etc. A simple change like below should do:

```
{% for index in range(1, num_servers+1) %}
{% for index2 in range(1, num_sizes+1) %}
  - name: "NB-{{ index2 }}-0{{ index }}"
    size: "size_{{ index2 }}"
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But if I will pass the value like this, size_{{ index2 }} then the final value of "size" parameter wouldn't be size: size_1, when in fact I want size to be the integer value, like size: 1, size: 2

Comment: Then wouldn't `size: {{ index2 }}` be enough?

Comment: No, because the size will be different, for example 100, 200. and the index2 will go up to maximum 4.